# Converting the type of a generic Collection in Java

Tags: java, generics, collections

In several spots in my code I have ArrayLists and TreeSets whose generic type I wish to convert. So for example I have an `ArrayList<Integer>` which I wish to convert to an `ArrayList<Long>`. Or I have a `TreeSet<BigInteger>` which I wish to convert to a `TreeSet<String>`.

All of these conversions can be made, but then I have to create for each type conversion a different function. Therefore I want to create a generic function whose signature looks something like this:

```
public static <Q,T> Collection<Q> convert(Collection<T> col, Class<Q> Q)
```

What I want is to get the class from `col` (e.g. `ArrayList`), create a new collection of that class and type `Q` (called `newCol`), and then iterate through `col` and convert each element which is of type `T` to type `Q` and add it to `newCol` and lastly return `newCol`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Using Java 8 it would be pretty simple. Can you use Java 8?

Answer (score 1):

There's no special mechanism like casting of incompatible classes in Java. You need to specify an explicit function which will perform a conversion. Using Java 8 it's really easy:

```
public static <Q,T,C extends Collection<Q>> C convert(Collection<T> col, Function<T, Q> fn, 
                   Supplier<C> supplier) {
    return col.stream().map(fn).collect(Collectors.toCollection(supplier));
}
```

Use it like this:

```
TreeSet<BigInteger> values = // fill them somehow
TreeSet<String> converted = convert(values, BigInteger::toString, TreeSet::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

**@Tagir Valeev** is right. You can do it easily in Java 8. But if you use Java 7, you can try to do something like this:

```
    public static <F, T> Collection<T> transform(Collection<F> fromCollection, Function<? super F, T> function) {
        return new TransformedCollection<F, T>(fromCollection, function);
    }

    static class TransformedCollection<F, T> extends AbstractCollection<T> {
        final Collection<F> fromCollection;
        final Function<? super F, ? extends T> function;

        TransformedCollection(Collection<F> fromCollection, Function<? super F, ? extends T> function) {
            this.fromCollection = checkNotNull(fromCollection);
            this.function = checkNotNull(function);
        }

        @Override public void clear() {
            fromCollection.clear();
        }

        @Override public boolean isEmpty() {
            return fromCollection.isEmpty();
        }

        @Override public Iterator<T> iterator() {
            return Iterators.transform(fromCollection.iterator(), function);
        }

        @Override public int size() {
            return fromCollection.size();
        }
    }
```

It's code from Guava library.